# Is it possible to extract password from HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\<SomeKey>?

Tags: windows-10, security

I did a Google search and found some [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-TSLSASecret-9bf94965) that extracted the user name, but not the password from a secret

```
HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\_SC_MyService
```

that was created after a service was registered (or created). See my [blog post](https://developernote.com/2019/11/accessing-a-service-credentials-on-windows-10) for more information on what experiments I did.

Is the password stored in the registry along with the user name? If yes, how to extract it?

Comment: user logon password is stored in the SAM file, it is encrypted. LSA secrets in the registry are also encrypted>>>>https://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=23

Comment: There is also a utility for de-crypting and dumping secrets>>>https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/lsa_secrets_dump.html